# Draw a plot in which the Y-axis text data (not numeric), and X-axis numeric data

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I can create a simple columnar diagram in a matplotlib according to the 'simple' dictionary:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())
plt.show()
```

[image]
But, how do I create curved line on the text and numeric data of this dictionarie, I do not know?

```
Т_OLD = {'10': 'need1', '11': 'need2', '12': 'need1', '13': 'need2', '14': 'need1'}
```

Like the picture below
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may use numpy to convert the dictionary to an array with two columns, which can be plotted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T_OLD = {'10' : 'need1', '11':'need2', '12':'need1', '13':'need2','14':'need1'}
x = list(zip(*T_OLD.items()))
# sort array, since dictionary is unsorted
x = np.array(x)[:,np.argsort(x[0])].T
# let second column be "True" if "need2", else be "False
x[:,1] = (x[:,1] == "need2").astype(int)

# plot the two columns of the array
plt.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1])
#set the labels accordinly
plt.gca().set_yticks([0,1])
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['need1', 'need2'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

The following would be a version, which is independent on the actual content of the dictionary; only assumption is that the keys can be converted to floats.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T_OLD = {'10': 'run', '11': 'tea', '12': 'mathematics', '13': 'run', '14' :'chemistry'}
x = np.array(list(zip(*T_OLD.items())))
u, ind = np.unique(x[1,:], return_inverse=True)
x[1,:] = ind
x = x.astype(float)[:,np.argsort(x[0])].T

# plot the two columns of the array
plt.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1])
#set the labels accordinly
plt.gca().set_yticks(range(len(u)))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(u)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in Python 3 raises the TypeError error: 'zip' object is not a sub script. Can you tell me how to fix this code?

Comment: What about `x = list(zip(*T_OLD.items()))`?

Comment: I tried, but Python 3 raises the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'False' (

Comment: Sorry, I only tested that with python 2.7. Now I updated the code and it should be wiorking with python 3 as well.

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing. How to write code for a dictionary of any length. If the dictionary is of arbitrary length and we do not want to explicitly specify the values (plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['need1', 'need2',....])).

Comment: If you have more than need1 and need2, better use atru's answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have already done atru's answer for it. Look, is it normal?

Comment: This program works only with this dictionary. But I would like to be able to submit any such dictionary to the input, and get a plot on the output and not change the program code (do not write down the names of the needs each time: "need1", "need2",...., in program code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157304/discussion-between-importanceofbeingernest-and-).

Comment: Hi! Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400324/sorting-the-values-by-their-increase-for-the-x-axis-for-a-two-dimensional-array . I'm trying to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use numeric values for your y-axis ticks, and then map them to desired strings with `plt.yticks()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

# example data
times = pd.date_range(start='2017-10-17 00:00', end='2017-10-17 5:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.choice([0,1], size=len(times))
data_labels = ['need1','need2']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(times, data, marker='o', linestyle="None")
plt.yticks(data, data_labels)
plt.xlabel("time")
```

[image]

Note: It's generally not a good idea to use a line graph to represent categorical changes in time (e.g. from `need1` to `need2`).  Doing that gives the visual impression of a continuum between time points, which may not be accurate.  Here, I changed the plotting style to points instead of lines.  If for some reason you need the lines, just remove `linestyle="None"` from the call to `plt.plot()`.

**UPDATE**
(per comments)

To make this work with a y-axis category set of arbitrary length, use `ax.set_yticks()` and `ax.set_yticklabels()` to map to y-axis values.

For example, given a set of potential y-axis values `labels`, let `N` be the size of a subset of `labels` (here we'll set it to 4, but it could be any size).

Then draw a random sample `data` of y values and plot against time, labeling the y-axis ticks based on the full set `labels`.  Note that we still use `set_yticks()` first with numerical markers, and then replace with our category labels with `set_yticklabels()`.

```
labels = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
N = 4

# example data
times = pd.date_range(start='2017-10-17 00:00', end='2017-10-17 5:00', freq='H')
data = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(labels)), size=len(times))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
ax.plot(times, data, marker='o', linestyle="None")
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.xlabel("time")
```

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing. How to write code for a dictionary of any length. If the dictionary is of arbitrary length and we do not want to explicitly specify the values (data_labels = ['need1','need2']).

Answer (score 2):

This gives the exact desired plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict

T_OLD = {'10' : 'need1', '11':'need2', '12':'need1', '13':'need2','14':'need1'}
T_SRT = OrderedDict(sorted(T_OLD.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

plt.plot(map(int, T_SRT.keys()), map(lambda x: int(x[-1]), T_SRT.values()),'r')

plt.ylim([0.9,2.1])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticks([1,2])
ax.set_yticklabels(['need1', 'need2'])

plt.title('T_OLD')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('need')

plt.show()
```

For Python 3.X the plotting lines needs to explicitly convert the `map()` output to lists:

```
plt.plot(list(map(int, T_SRT.keys())), list(map(lambda x: int(x[-1]), T_SRT.values())),'r')
```

as in Python 3.X `map()` returns an iterator as opposed to a list in Python 2.7.

The plot uses the dictionary keys converted to ints and last elements of `need1` or `need2`, also converted to ints. This relies on the particular structure of your data, if the values where `need1` and `need3` it would need a couple more operations.

After plotting and changing the axes limits, the program simply modifies the tick labels at y positions 1 and 2. It then also adds the title and the x and y axis labels.

Important part is that the dictionary/input data has to be sorted. One way to do it is to use `OrderedDict`. Here `T_SRT` is an `OrderedDict` object sorted by keys in `T_OLD`.

The output is:

[image]

This is a more general case for more values/labels in `T_OLD`. It assumes that the label is always `'needX'` where `X` is any number. This can readily be done for a general case of any string preceding the number though it would require more processing,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

T_OLD = {'10' : 'need1', '11':'need8', '12':'need11', '13':'need1','14':'need3'}
T_SRT = OrderedDict(sorted(T_OLD.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

x_val = list(map(int, T_SRT.keys()))
y_val = list(map(lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[-1]), T_SRT.values()))

plt.plot(x_val, y_val,'r')

plt.ylim([0.9*min(y_val),1.1*max(y_val)])
ax = plt.gca()
y_axis = list(set(y_val))
ax.set_yticks(y_axis)
ax.set_yticklabels(['need' + str(i) for i in y_axis])

plt.title('T_OLD')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('need')

plt.show()
```

This solution finds the number at the end of the label using `re.findall` to accommodate for the possibility of multi-digit numbers. Previous solution just took the last component of the string because numbers were single digit. It still assumes that the number for plotting position is the last number in the string, hence the `[-1]`. Again for Python 3.X map output is explicitly converted to list, step not necessary in Python 2.7.

The labels are now generated by first selecting unique y-values using `set` and then renaming their labels through concatenation of the strings `'need'` with its corresponding integer.

The limits of y-axis are set as 0.9 of the minimum value and 1.1 of the maximum value. Rest of the formatting is as before.

The result for this test case is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in Python 3 raises the TypeError error: 'zip' object is not a sub script. Can you tell me how to fix this code?

Comment: Added the line that you need in Python 3, just for the future reference.

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing. How to write code for a dictionary of any length. If the dictionary is of arbitrary length and we do not want to explicitly specify the values (ax.set_yticklabels(['need1', 'need2']),....])).

Comment: You mean there would be more lables like need1 and need2, maybe need3, need4 etc? I'll add it soon.

Comment: Yes, now this program works only with this dictionary. But I would like to be able to submit any such dictionary to the input, and get a plot on the output and not change the program code (do not write down the names of the needs each time: "need1", "need2",...., in program code).

Comment: Here it is. I'll extend it later for any string just for completeness, but are all your strings named "need" with number at the end? If they're not I'll extend it sooner. Otherwise, this assumes the above and does the trick.

Comment: You are brilliant! I will deal with your decision. Another question of curiosity? If I did not tire you. If instead of 'needs' there were their names, for example: T_OLD = {'10': 'run', '11': 'tea', '12': 'mathematics', '13': 'physics', '14', :'chemistry'}. What code would a program have?

Comment: Thanks :) I liked the question, useful for the future. That depends - you would need to determine a rule how to assign values to the labels, say physics is 5, math is 3 etc., then you could do various things, like combine them into tuples and get the number - label pair from there. You can always try and post another question.