# Plotting a chart a plot in which the Y text data and X numeric data from dictionary. Matplotlib & Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

Together we managed to solve a similar problem. We use numeric values for your y-axis ticks, and then map them to desired strings with plt.xticks().

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

T_OLD = {'10' : 'need1', '11':'need8', '12':'need11', '13':'need1','14':'need3'}
T_SRT = OrderedDict(sorted(T_OLD.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

x_val = list(map(int, T_SRT.keys()))
y_val = list(map(lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+', x)[-1]), T_SRT.values()))

plt.plot(x_val, y_val,'r')

plt.ylim([0.9*min(y_val),1.1*max(y_val)])
ax = plt.gca()
y_axis = list(set(y_val))
ax.set_yticks(y_axis)
ax.set_yticklabels(['need' + str(i) for i in y_axis])

plt.title('T_OLD')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('need')

plt.show()
```

[image]

But how to change this program, If instead of 'needs' there were their names, for example:

```
T_OLD = {'10': 'run', '11': 'tea', '12': 'mathematics', '13': 'run', '14', :'chemistry'}.
```

What code would a program have?

The result should look like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797395/4124317) from the former post? It will directly work with your dictionary,and produce a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNuq5.png).

Comment: Hello! The question to which you sent, this is my first question.
Colleagues asked me to form a new question. Can it be reformulated differently?

Comment: Why do you need to ask a new question, when the answer is already given in your previous question? If you want to ask something which hasn't been answered already, you can reformulate the question.